# ElasticSearch how to manage the score result in ngram query?

Tags: elasticsearch, n-gram

I have hundreds of chemicals results in my index *climate_change*

I'm using a ngram research and this is the settings that I'm using for the index.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 30,
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "test_ngram",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          },
          "search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "test_ngram",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ]
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "test_ngram": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 1,
            "max_gram": 30,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My main problem is that if I try to do a query like this one

```
GET climate_change/_search?size=1000
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query":"oxygen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I see that a lot of results have the **same score 7.381186**..but it's strange

```
     {
        "_index" : "climate_change",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "XXX",
        "_score" : 7.381186,
        "_source" : {
          "recordtype" : "chemicals",
          "description" : "carbon/oxygen"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "climate_change",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "YYY",
        "_score" : 7.381186,
        "_source" : {
          "recordtype" : "chemicals",
          "description" : "oxygen"
        }
```

How could it be possible?
In the example above, If I'm using *ngram* and I'm searching **oxygen** in the *description* field, I'll expect that the second result will have a score **bigger** than the first one.
I've also tried to specify the type of the tokenizer "*standard*" and "*whitespace*" in the settings, but it could not help.
Maybe is the '**/**' character inside the description?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the analyzer in the mapping for the `description` field also.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "test_ngram",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "search_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "test_ngram",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "test_ngram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 30,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "description": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "recordtype": "chemicals",
  "description": "carbon/oxygen"
}
{
  "recordtype": "chemicals",
  "description": "oxygen"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "description": {
        "query":"oxygen"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67180160",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.89246297,
        "_source": {
          "recordtype": "chemicals",
          "description": "oxygen"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67180160",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.6651374,
        "_source": {
          "recordtype": "chemicals",
          "description": "carbon/oxygen"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot! :)